# Drupal user profile image disappears after logout

Tags: drupal, user-profile

We are running Drupal 7.  When a user uploads a new image, the image saves and displays correctly.

When a user logs out, the image disappears from the profile, but remains in the images folder.

We traced the problem back to logout action somehow setting the "picture" column in the users table to 0 immediately after logout.

The trouble is, I cannot find this where in the code this happens.  I found a user_logout function, but that does not do it.

Comment: Are you setting the uploaded image's status to `$img->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;`?

Comment: Inside the module code, there is this:
$picture->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

Comment: Here is the complete thread of findings:
http://drupal.org/node/1368634

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed.  We had to update the avatar modules and the reference to the database.